# How to speed up the search by patterns matching and modifying a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I need to classify URLs from a DataFrame and modify it by exact match and contains conditions:

```
class PageClassifier:
    def __init__(self, contains_pat, match_pat):
        """
        :param match_pat: A dict with exact match patterns in values as lists
        :type match_pat: dict
        :param contains_pat: A dict with contains patterns in values as lists
        :type contains_pat: dict
        """
        self.match_pat = match_pat
        self.contains_pat = contains_pat

    def worker(self, data_frame):
        """
        Classifies pages by type (url patterns)
        :param data_frame: DataFrame to classify
        :return: Classified by URL patterns DataFrame
        """
        try:
            for key, value in self.contains_pat.items():
                reg_exp = '|'.join(value)
                data_frame.loc[data_frame['url'].str.contains(reg_exp, regex=True), ['page_class']] = key

            for key, value in self.match_pat.items():
                data_frame.loc[data_frame['url'].isin(value), ['page_class']] = key

            return data_frame

        except Exception as e:
            print('page_classifier(): ', e, type(e))


df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv',
                     delimiter='\t', parse_dates=['date'],
                     chunksize=1000000)    
contains = {'catalog': ['/category/', '/tags', '/search'], 'resources': ['.css', '.js', '.woff', '.ttf', '.html', '.php']}
match = {'info_pages': ['/information', '/about-us']}
    
classify = PageClassifier(contains, match)

new_pd = pd.DataFrame()
for num, chunk in enumerate(df):
    print('Start chunk ', num)
    new_pd = pd.concat([new_pd, classify.worker(chunk)])
new_pd.to_csv('classified.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

But it is very slow and takes to much RAM when I work with files over 10GB.
How can I search and modify data faster? I need "exact match" and "contains" patterns searching in one func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice here that will tank performance the most is:

```
new_pd = pd.concat([new_pd, classify.worker(chunk)])
```

cs95 outlines this issue very well in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/15497888). The general advice is "NEVER grow a DataFrame!". Essentially creating a new copy of the DataFrame in each iteration is quadratic in time complexity as the entire DataFrame is copied each iteration, *and* the DataFrame only gets larger which ends up costing more and more time.

If we wanted to improve this approach we might consider something like:

```
df_list = []
for num, chunk in enumerate(df):
    df_list.append(classify.worker(chunk))

new_pd = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
new_pd.to_csv('classified.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

However, assuming we don't ever need the entire DataFrame in memory at once, and given that our `logs.csv` is so large that we need to *read it* in chunks, we should also consider *writing out* our DataFrame in chunks:

```
for num, chunk in enumerate(df):
    classify.worker(chunk).to_csv(
        'classified.csv', sep='\t', index=False,
        header=(num == 0),  # only write the header for the first chunk,
        mode='w' if num == 0 else 'a'  # append mode after the first iteration
    )
```

---

In terms of reading in the file, we appear to only using the `url` and `page_class` columns. Since we're not using the DateTime functionality of the `date` column we don't need to take the time to parse it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv', delimiter='\t', chunksize=1000000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Especially for "header=(num == 0), mode='w' if num == 0 else 'a'".  This was very useful example for my practice.